# Ubuntu crashes / freezes after RAM upgrade

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade, ram

So basically I needed a RAM upgrade for my pc and I bought 2x8GB to replace the 2x2 I had.

However, instead of using the capability of the 16 GB of RAM my computer is more instable. Crashes, is some software runs slow or throttles for some reason.

I'm not even using more than the RAM I used to have. I'm around 20% which would be approximately 4 GB of ram (the limit I had before). The computer does not crash if I do not go beyond 3.2 GB of RAM being used (which is less than my previous 3.7).

After crashing and booting the computer again took me to linux busybox system and I had to do `fsck /dev/sda1`.

Here is the imgur album with my computer details and screens of the situation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrANy.jpg

Can someone please help me in figuring out how I can enjoy the most performance of my computer under this new situation?

This is frustating as previously working with the computer was hard because it got stuck but it never crashed.

Now I'm basically scared of opening a program on the idea that it might just crash again. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

[image]

this image was taken when it crashed. Mouse was stuck (check crosshair). Clicking combination of keys dos nothing. Computer was completely dead. Why is this happening exactly?

Comment: when CPU usage increases what process is consuming most of the CPU power? can you update that info too?

Comment: Check if Your RAM has proper voltage set in BIOS, sometimes bios sets lower values. Make sure the voltage is at proper level.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh An angular app running in localhost which is not yet optimized so it consumes quite CPU. However it always worked in my 4GB...

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz how exactly can I check that and which values should be set?

Comment: @Fane That really depends on Your bios - check its manual.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips come to mind in case its the hardware.
When you just use 1 module, do you have the same behavior?
Are the sockets clean?
Are the module(s) pushed well down into the socket.
Load Default Settings in BIOS after adding/removing a module.